# show image which is served by express in nodejs

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I serve image from local hard drive in node express using sendfile like :

```
   app.get('/data/getImage/:Id', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.Id);

    res.sendfile('C:\\defaultimg.png', function(error){
        if(error)
            console.log(error.message);
        else
            console.log('File transferd successfully.');
    })
});
```

and I call this method in angular and get data like:

```
var resource = $resource('/data/getImage/:id', {id: '@id'}, {getImage: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}});
            resource.get({id: _id}, function (image) {
                console.log('getImageById');
                console.log(image);
                callback(image);
            });
```

so, my question is how i can i show this received data in image tag ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the image path some where on your scope and then use `ng-src`.

```
<img ng-src="{{scopePropertyWithImageUrl}}" />
```

Link to the documentation: [`ng-src`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSrc).

Comment: so this is obvious, but I want to do my approach actually.

Comment: This is how it works. If you want to transport the images itself throught an Ajax request you could decode them with Base64 which make them ~40% larger and does not work in all browsers, but still uses the `ng-src` directive.